# Enable Horizontal Scroll Mobile Only/ Disabled on Dekstop

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am creating a website with Wordpress.

I need to make a ImageMap plugin responsive. The only solution is to make it scrollable on Mobile devices. Because if image is made resposive with     `width:100%;` and `overflow-x:scroll;` its also scrollable on Dekstop.

I tried also with:  `@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width: 480px)`. Thought maybe there was problems in this code, so searched and tried every answer from stackoverflow.com, didn't helped. [My Site](http://grazizeme.pcz.lt)

Made a ticket for that plugin, but I need fast answer, client is waiting.

**How to achieve scrolling in mobile only, while dekstop responsive using CSS?**

```css
@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width: 480px){
    #image-map-pro-3521{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    left: 0; 
    top: 0;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    }
    .container {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        overflow-x:scroll;
    }
}

#image-map-pro-3521{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
.imp-wrap{
     min-width:100%; min-height:100%; width:auto; height:auto;
}
.container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.container .row {
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css works top down and something further down will over wright something higher in the page. So what you have is

```
@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width: 480px){
#image-map-pro-3521{
overflow-x:scroll;
}

#image-map-pro-3521{
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

so whatever happens overflow-x will always be hidden as it is not surrounded by an conditional statement and is further down the page. So to fix it either put the @media stuff at the bottom of the css or put a conditional statement around the general stuff. The better option is to rearrange the css unless you expect browsers who cant process @media tags.

side note: why are you concerned about the min width? dose anything different happen under 360px wide? if not then you dont need the min width statement, this should save a little bit of bandwidth and help the page load a tiny bit faster.

Comment: Ooh, stupid me... Thanks for your answer, it was so simple and I couldn't think of it. Well that happens when you work alone. Btw, thanks for side note, you are right. Going to use your advice!

Comment: no problems, the main reason i know about this is because i have done slimier things.